# Spring rest client + camunda rest api: postForObject only accept camunda.bpm JSONObject but JacksonMessageConverter only takes javax JsonObject

Tags: spring, resttemplate, json

I'm trying to build a rest client with Springframework's RestTemplate but the problem is that my api is Camunda Rest Api.

That means that I can only send Camunda.bpm's `JSONObject` type through `postForObject` but my `JacksonJsonConverter` only parses javax's `JsonObject`.

I'm getting either the

`no message converter found for the request type camunda JSONObject`

or the

`bad media type` exception when I use `JSONObject` type and `JsonObject` type respectively.

New to spring and been stuck for several days, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on how MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter actually works and taking a closer look at Camunda REST API's request content format, I found that the problem lies in Jackson converter not able to parse anything that doesn't starts with the ArrayList start token "[". Since I have to pass a request with the start token "{" as requested by Camunda, I wrote my own Jackson converter. Specifically, I override the readJavaType() method in Jackson2:

```
private Object readJavaType(JavaType javaType, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) {
        try {

            String parseInput = "["+convertStreamToString(inputMessage.getBody())+"]";
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(parseInput.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return this.objectMapper.readValue(stream, javaType);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```